# Background uploading with Dropbox iOS API

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-upload, background, dropbox-api

I am trying to get my app to continue uploading to Dropbox once it's put into the background, but I can't seem to figure out why it doesn't work.

Apple's docs give 2 ways to do this which I understand as:
 1. Do something within a given time frame
 2. Do one of our pre-ordained activities

Given that the Dropbox API doesn't expose an NSURLSession and [Apple's closest explanation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) in the docs is geared towards "downloading" in the background, I assumed that the correct way is to go for approach 1, so I wrapped my code in the block Apple suggested, but once I close the app it stops.

```
__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"UploadImages" expirationHandler:^{
    // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you
    // stopped or ending the task outright.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];

// Start the long-running task and return immediately.    
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // Do the work associated with the task, preferably in chunks.
    for (PHAsset *currentImage in images) {
        [self.imageManager requestImageDataForAsset:currentImage options:opts resultHandler:^(NSData *imageData, NSString *dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary *info) {
            // set some variables...and then call Dropbox upload
            [self.restClient uploadFile:fileName toPath:destPath withParentRev:nil fromPath:filePath];
        }
    }

    [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
});
```

I've also requested that the app allows network activity. It doesn't seem to make a difference
[image: required background mode settings]

I'm pretty new to iOS so any guidance would be helpful. Maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: `self.restClient uploadFile` is non-blocking so perhaps it's returning right away? It uses a delegate so you might have to wait until the delegate returns before calling `[application endBackgroundTask:bgTask]`.